# show table of users in web form asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an admin page where the admin can press a button and a table of all the users signed up to the website is shown. The button:

```
        <button type="button" id="allusers" name="allusers">Show all users</button>
```

And the table:

```
    <div id="allusersList" runat="server" name="allusersList" style="display: none;"></div>
```

some simple jquery:

```
$("#allusers").click(function () {
    $("#allusersList").show();
});
```

And the c# code:

```
string filename = "database.mdf";
    string tablename = "users";
    string selectQuery = "select * from " + tablename;
    DataTable table = Eitan.ExecuteDataTable(filename, selectQuery);
    int length = table.Rows.Count;
    if (length > 0)
    {
        st += "<table style='margin-top: 400px; margin-left: 100px; border: 1px solid black;'>";
        st += "<tr style='border: 2px solid black;'>";
        st += "<th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;' >Full Name</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Username</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Password</th>";
        st += "<th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Email</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Cell</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Birthday</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Age</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Gender</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center; padding:5px;'>Admin?</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Update</th> <th style='border: 2px solid black; text-align: center;'>Delete</th>";
        st += "</tr>";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            st += "<tr>";
            st += "<form method='post' action='edituserAdmin.aspx'>";
            st += "<input type='hidden' name='fullname' value='" + table.Rows[i]["fullname"] + "'/>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'>" + table.Rows[i]["fullname"] + "</td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='text' name='username' value='" + table.Rows[i]["username"] + "'/></td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='password' name='password' value='" + table.Rows[i]["password"] + "'/></td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='text' name='email' value='" + table.Rows[i]["email"] + "'/></td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='text' name='cell' value='" + table.Rows[i]["cell"] + "'/></td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='birthday' name='birthday' value='" + table.Rows[i]["birthday"] + "'/></td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='text' name='age' value='" + table.Rows[i]["age"] + "'/></td>";
            st += "<td style='padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='text' name='gender' value='" + table.Rows[i]["gender"] + "'/></td>";
            if ((bool)table.Rows[i]["admin"] == true)
            {
                st += "<td style='text-align: center; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='checkbox' style='width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-left: 22px;' name='admin' value='true' checked class='checkbox disabled' disabled /></td>";
                st += "<td style='text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; padding: 10px;'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-primary' name='updateuserAdmin' id='updateuserAdmin' /></td>";
                st += "<td style='text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; padding: 10px;'><a href='deleteuserAdmin.aspx'><input type='button' value='Delete' name='deleteuserAdmin' class='btn btn-warning disabled' id='deleteuserAdmin' disabled/></a></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                st += "<td style='padding: 10px; text-align: center; border: 2px solid black;'><input type='checkbox' style='width: 20px; height: 20px;' name='admin' value='true'/></td>";
                st += "<td style='text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; padding: 10px;'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-primary' name='updateuserAdmin' id='updateuserAdmin' /></td>";
                st += "<td style='text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; padding: 10px;'><a href='deleteuserAdmin.aspx'><input type='button' value='Delete' name='deleteuserAdmin' class='btn btn-warning' id='deleteuserAdmin' /></a></td>";
            }

            st += "</form>";
            st += "</tr>";
        }
        st += "</table>";
        allusersList.InnerHtml = st;
    }
```

And the Eitan.ExecuteDataTable function is:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string fileName, string sql)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    tableAdapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

When I run the website and click the button, nothing happens. I tried to see if it was a problem with the jQuery code but it works with showing other things. So how can I fix it?

Thanks! Sorry if something is unclear or not written well.. I'm a beginner :)

Comment: `StringBuilder()` please. For the love of god, `StringBuilder()`

Comment: ... And then AngularJS.  God, it makes code so much more readable !!

Comment: your div is having a runat="server" attribute. have you checked the id that is being generated for the div? if you have a master page, chances are that your div id might be different.

Comment: I'm not really sure what StringBuilder() is..

Comment: I am not sure, but hope this will help
    $("#allusersList").toggle();

Comment: @eitanmayer if you are not sure what `StringBuilder()` is then do a google search and understand the difference between mutable and immutable strings are msdn has some good documentation as well as examples in regards to C#

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the website and click the button, nothing happens. I tried
>   to see if it was a problem with the jQuery code but it works with
>   showing other things. So how can I fix it?

First thing you can do: run it in Chrome, hit F12 to show the Developer options, then go into the Console tab, and see if any JavaScript errors are silently occurring.

Whenever I read a JavaScript problem with the words "nothing happens", that normally means a JavaScript error has occurred !

Answer (score 0):

If the table is populated accurately, then the jquery part should work. If the problem still exists then the only problem can be 
clientidmode= "Static", because webforms appends extra strings to the id, by mentioning clientidmode="Static" in the div tag will render the div id as it is in the Id property. After adding the clientidmode="Static" your tag will looks like

```
<div id="allusersList" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" name="allusersList" style="display: none;"></div>
```

without adding clientidmode="Static" you can write in your jquery like this

```
$("#allusers").click(function () {
    $("#<%=allusersList.ClientID%>").show();
});
```

Hope this will help